# Apache Commons Email encode attach with base64

Tags: java, base64, apache-commons-email

I'm trying to send a file base64-encoded via `apache.commons.mail` and I just can't seam to get the `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` header where it's supposed to go.

```
// Create the email
MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
email.setSmtpPort(587);
email.setDebug(false);
email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
email.setAuthentication("from@gmail.com", "password");
email.setTLS(true);

email.addTo("to@example.com");
email.setFrom("from@example.com");
email.setSubject("subject");

email.attach(new ByteArrayDataSource(
     Base64.encodeBase64(attachFull.getBytes()), "text/plain"), 
     "samplefile.txt", 
     "sample file desc", 
     EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT
);
```

And this is what gets to the recipient.

```
------=_Part_0_614021571.1334210788719
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=Cp1252; name=texto.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=samplefile.txt
Content-Description: sample file desc
```

**How I can specify that the file is Base64 encoded?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try overriding the [`attach`](http://commons.apache.org/email/api-release/org/apache/commons/mail/MultiPartEmail.html#attach%28%29) method and set the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header in there. By default the framework doesn't set it for you or expose the MIME bodyPart cleanly.

Comment: That may do... I've had some success adding a `MimeMultipart()` (javax.mail) as an external part to commons.mail. But something's still not right. I may be messing the Base64 encoding. Let me dig a bit further...

Comment: Accepted your answer as it put me on track. Posted mine as a reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution would be to do something like this:

```
// create a multipart leg for a specific attach
MimeMultipart part = new MimeMultipart();
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler (new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(attachFull.getBytes(), "text/plain")));
messageBodyPart.removeHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding");
messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
part.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
email.addPart(part);
```

And javax will automatically convert your file to base64.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I used the answer to manipulate body transfer encoding, works as well. I only needed to drop `removeHeader` call.