# Send image attachment from base64 string using Groovy and Apache commons

Tags: groovy, base64, mime, apache-commons

I'm writing a process to send out emails to customers in a system that uses Groovy and has the [apache.commons.mail.*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/mail/util/MimeMessageUtils.html) libs installed already (although I can install others if absolutely necessary).

The problem is that the images are passed to me as a base64 encoded string.  I've considered saving them as an image, and then attaching them via URL ([here are some examples of sending an email with attachments](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html)) , but it seems like a waste of a step to decode for them to be re-encoded.  Is there a way to attach the image directly?

I've found [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118348/apache-commons-email-encode-attach-with-base64) other [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110091/base64-encoded-images-in-email-signatures) with [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981724/java-mail-base64-encoded-string-to-image-attachment), but they either seem to give an unsatisfactory answer for my situation or rely on other Java versions/libraries I don't have access to.

EDIT:

Here's where I am with it now (thanks to JerryP's comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110091/base64-encoded-images-in-email-signatures/29205203#29205203)):

```
def my_img = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB...";
byte[] img_bytes = b64_data.src.drop(b64_data.src.indexOf(',')+1).decodeBase64();  // This extracts the encoded part
def type = b64_data.src.substring(b64_data.src.indexOf(':') + 1, b64_data.src.indexOf(';') ); // This extracts the data type from the long base64 string (i.e. 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA...')

enc_attachments = ByteArrayDataSource( img_bytes, type );
```

So, I have a `ByteArrayDataSource` of my image now, but [the `embed` calls in apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/HtmlEmail.html#embed(javax.activation.DataSource,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) don't take ByteArrayDataSource as a param.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out.  The above actually works, I just missed the 'new' keyword before ByteArrayDataSource, so it was giving me some weirdness when I went to send.  So the final code is something like this:

```
def my_img = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQAB...";
def filename = "foo.jpg";
byte[] img_bytes = my_img.drop(my_img.indexOf(',')+1).decodeBase64();  // This extracts the encoded part
def type = my_img.substring(my_img.indexOf(':') + 1, my_img.indexOf(';') ); // This extracts the data type from the long base64 string (i.e. 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA...')

enc_attachment = new ByteArrayDataSource( img_bytes, type );

// ... set up email stuff here

def cid = email.embed(enc_attachment, filename);
attachment_str += '<img src="cid: ' + cid + '" />';  // email.embed() returns a random 'cid'
// put attachment_str in your message before sending in order to embed.
```